# YII vs Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, yii

HI Folks!

I developed my early projects using [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/).

I was having a look over [YII Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

After spending few moments it was looking good and similar to Ruby On Rails.

Has anyone else evaluated it?

Is this a good bet to go?

Please provide your valuable feedbacks.

Thanks in advance.